# How to import/read a graph, written as edges list and saved as a txt file, into Networkit?

Tags: python, graph, networkit

**Hi, how can I read/import a graph, stored in a text file, `mygraph.txt`, and written in a form of edges list (column 1: node `u`, column 2: node `v`)**

```
1 2  
1 3  
1 4 
2 5 
3 4 
3 5
```

**into Networkit?**

**I guess something like this?**

```
G = readGraph("/home/JohnRambo/Documents/myFolder/mygraph.txt")
```

P.S.: After several attempts I am not able yet to make it work...and I did not find clear instructions in the networkit guide!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
from networkit import *  
import networkit as nk 
G = nk.readGraph("/home/JohnRambo/Documents/myFolder/mygraph.txt",nk.Format.SNAP)
print(G.numberOfNodes(), G.numberOfEdges())
```

Output:

```
5 6
```